# Serializing SOAP XML to Java - Android

Tags: android, json, xml, soap

I have XML coming back from a SOAP request that has arrays inside of arrays, what is the best way to serialize XML from SOAP to a Java class in Android?

Converting the SOAP XML to JSON and then using GSON is not an option because when an array has only one element i get "JsonObject is not an array"..

Just looking for an awesome gradle plugin that i can use, or something really good.  Surely there's a better way than what is in Google docs for Android...

Comment: Did u googled it? Have you heard about XMLParser ?

Comment: Yeah i Googled it, XMLParser doesn't seem to map xml directly to an object.  i found https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml which looks a lot nicer